# Get full URL of images in media library including http://

Tags: images, http

media file has `//example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/logo.png` without `http:`.

How to change it?

[image: picture URL without http://]

I need full `http://` address in my posts

Comment: Is it only 1 image where http is missing?

Comment: Did you set the URL with http (via settings > general)?

Comment: Hi Sergei. The `//url/` is _"protocol-relative URL"_ which makes it possible to access both `http` and `https`, depending on your connection. It's a good practice to have it. What's your problem with this? :)

Comment: Luckyfella: All images in my wordpress has this type of adress :( No additional setting in my Settings-general

Comment: I need to change URL because Facebook Crossposting Plugin don't want to get my posts with this type of url (//site.com/image.jpg)... it needs full path

Comment: and i already have https; on this site

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure some plugin or your theme modifies your attachment url. 
Try to find `wp_get_attachment_url` hook in your code or simply create your own with high priority this way:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', function($url) {
 return preg_replace("~^//(.+)$~", "https://$1", $url);
}, 999);
```

or better:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', function($url) {
  return set_url_scheme($url, 'https');
}, 999);
```

But I recommend you to find the reason of this attachment url behavior first.

Comment: Thx Anton - помогло :) !

Comment: You are welcome! I will appreciate if you will mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs in your media library are protocol-relative. This means, no matter if you are on a secure protocol or simply HTTP, the link is always following the domain's protocol.

Now, if you are experiencing problem, there is something you can do which is not recommended.

First, make a back-up! There is **"No"** going back if you make a mistake. Back-up, and back-up everything.

Then, download and install [Better search replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin. This allows you to replace strings in your database, including serialized data.

Head over to plugin's page, and replace:

> //yourdomain.com/

with

> https://yourdomain.com/

Pay attention to slashes, spaces, etc. *"Everything"* matters here, even a capitalized letter might matter.

Comment: sorry, but you don't understand me. Please, go to your media-library  - there you can see full URL address with http:// - it does not mean - that it Mysql database URL has http://......  it database we have protocol-relative url..

Comment: [My media library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsNHP.jpg) works fine, here is an screenshot.

Comment: yes ! i have many wordpress web-sites, and all of them had http:// in media-library URLs... so it's normal !